# How to include Django CSRF token in request through ngrok?

Tags: python, django, csrf, facebook-login, ngrok

I am building a Django app that will be hosted on a local network and perform authentication using Facebook Login. Since Facebook Login requires the callback address for a login to either be localhost or publicly-addressable, I'm using ngrok to create an address for Facebook to return data to.

After the user logs in with Facebook, I perform a POST with AJAX from the template with their data to a local view (/fb_login) which saves to my database in Django. Since authentication is based on this database, I don't think it's wise to avoid the CSRF checks Django performs on this view.

To include the CSRF token in the POST to /fb_login, I'm using the following which a few forums suggested:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
            // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
        }
    }
});
```

This should only include the CSRF token to relative URLs (which I understand to be the best practice). When I run the server on localhost and perform the Facebook Login from the same machine, this works fine. However, when I run the system on localhost and access it through ngrok from another machine on the local network and perform the Facebook Login, I get a 403 and a message saying the CSRF check failed. This leads me to believe that the ngrok URL isn't considered "local", so the CSRF token isn't being set.

Assuming I know what my ngrok URL is at the time my Django server starts, can I include it in what's considered a "local" address for the purposes of including the CSRF token? Is there another way to do this securely? As a note, web development is not my area, so please let me know if I'm misunderstanding something here. Thanks!

Comment: any news regarding this?